# Как восстановить поврежденную базу MS Access?

Tags: access

Необходимо восстановить поврежденную базу MS Access. Встроенными средствами не получается, уже пробовал. Access вылетает с ошибкой во время попытки 
восстановления. Упомяну еще про ос, пользуюсь Windows 10. Есть такая же рабочая база, примерно месячной давности, структура, запросы и т.п. там такие же, то есть восстановить надо только данные таблиц. А вот при попытке "сжать/восстановить" рабочую базу, Access вылетает точно таким же образом.
Есть ли какие способы восстановить из нее данные?

Comment: Может там от файла остались одни нули и рожки да ножки, а, следовательно, и восстанавливать нечего. Так что гадание по кофейной гуще.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте новую базу и импортируйте туда объекты из поврежденной. Как правило это помогает, если нет физических повреждений самого файла. Также на рынке есть достаточно много сторонних утилит для восстановления поврежденных файлов, у большинства есть пробные версии, позволяющие увидеть, что данные можно вытащить.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен что поможет, но вдруг. Если база .mdb формата, можно попробовать вытянуть данные через утилиту BatchAccess:
https://rsdn.ru/article/files/progs/BatchAccess.xml